# MS SQL: Как сделать автоматическую нумерацию в таблице, и начинать заново в зависимости от текущего года

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Имеется такая таблица, которая используется для регистрации отчётов

```
CREATE TABLE LVD.dbo.SampleReports (
   ID INT IDENTITY,
   ReportNum INT NULL, //номер отчёта
   ReportDate DATE NULL,  //дата отчёта
   CONSTRAINT PK_SampleReports_SampleReportID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SampleReportID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Как сделать, чтобы в столбец `ReportNum` при создании записи автоматически присваивался порядковый номер, при этом, чтобы при смене года в `ReportDate` (например закончился 2022 начался 2023) нумерация начиналась снова с 1.

Comment: Это достаточно распространённая задача. Есть нюансы, в зависимости от которых реализация может иметь тот или иной вид. 1) Будут ли удаляться записи из таблицы? 2) Если удаляется запись с максимальным номером по году, можно ли выдавать этот же номер опять новому отчёту? 3) Есть ли требование потокобезопасности? 4) Вряд ли, но вдруг - нужна ли максимизация пропускной способности операции регистрации?

Comment: можно завести секвенс, который сбрасывать на исходное 31.12 в 23:59:59

Comment: @teran как вариант, да, только сложно будет отслеживать 31.12 23:59:59 - накладных расходов много, как мне кажется

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin запланированное задание которое раз в год выполняется. вряд ли принесет много расходов.

Comment: @teran допустим отчёты идут без остановки. Где гарантия, что джоба стартанёт секунда в секунду? Да и расписание джобы - это запуск задания, а не выполнения. Допустим на сервсере нагрузка и выполнение скрипта приостановлено и т.п. На серьёзном проекте, я бы так не делал

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin зачем гадать про "допустим"? Подобных вводных от ТС пока что не было.

Comment: По уточняющим вопросам: 
В рассматриваемом случае нагрузка небольшая - пару отчётов в день. 
Требований к  потокобезопасности нет. 
Удаление записей возможно.

Comment: @sky_diez если пара отчётов в день - то таблица небольшая и вьюха будет нормально отрабатывать. А создавать дополнительны сущности в виде сиквенса и джобы для неё - как-то расточительно(по моим ощущениям). Да и помнить про это всё, документировать и т.д. слишком сложно для такой задачи

Comment: @teran Это называется проектирование, а не гадание. Проектировать нужно, чтобы предсказать возможные нештатные ситуации - чем сложнее схема, тем больше мест для обдумывания потенциальных поломок

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin сиквенс то есть это дополнительная сущность - зло, а вьюха, конечно, дополнительной не будет? :D

Comment: при двух отчетах в день можно и подзапросом генерировать номер при создании и не заморачиваться

Comment: @sky_diez, а по 2) всё-таки что? Скажем, есть отчёт №26, а следующего пока нет. Удалили №26. Следующий должен иметь №27, или можно опять назначить №26?

Comment: @i-one нужно опять  назначить 26

Comment: тогда при генерации выбирайте max +1 да и все на этом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести вьюшку, в которой будет такой столбец:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(ReportDate) ORDER BY Id) AS ReportNum
```

Comment: если вставить отчет задним числом, то у уже существующих изменится нумерация что ли? Задач была не пронумеровать отчеты по годам, а сгенерировать и присвоить номер, который не будет изменяться от внешних условий

Comment: @teran спокойнее. Можно добавить сортировку по Id: "...ORDER BY Id...", было бы желание решить проблему, а не искать её

Comment: вычисление номера документа в любое случае не очень хорошая затея. Эта вещь должна быт  неизменной. А различного рода махинации по ее подсчету могут приводить к неоднозначному результату (в данном случае вы не можете гарантировать что номер всегда будет одинаков, банально удалив отчеты из середины, у вас собьется нумерация. Но и вставки отчета заданным id в середину тоже возможны), вдобавок это избыточная работа. И конкретно в этой реализации еще, накидывая функцию на потенциальный столбец индекса, этот индекс не будет использоваться.